# How to Display Unicode font in eclipse layout designer for android

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, unicode

I have the following resource in my `strings.xml`

```
<string name="punjabi">ਪੰਜਾਬੀ</string>
```

This gets displayed in the Android string resource editor and my application just fine.

However in the eclipse layout editor, the characters display as boxes, similar to `□□□□□□`

The box characters indicate a font glyph look up failure.

Any ideas on how to get Eclipse to display `unicode` in the layout designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need.  The font itself, and the fallback mapping.

First, copy the font needed, such as Lohit-Punjabi.ttf into the platform specific fonts directory:
 `sdk\platforms\android-###\data\fonts`

Second, add the fallback font into the font definition file in that directory:

For android SDK version up to **13** add the following line in **fonts.xml**

```
<fallback ttf="Lohit-Punjabi" />
```

For android SDK version **14** and up add the following line in **fallback_fonts.xml**

```
<family>
  <fileset>
    <file>Lohit-Punjabi.ttf</file>
  </fileset>
</family>
```